# Getting error Error: Can't resolve all parameters with testbed

Tags: angular, jasmine, angular8, ngrx

I am writing unit test case for NGRX effect

**app.effects.ts**

```js
    Injectable()
    export class AppEffects {
      constructor(
        private actions$: Actions,
        private appHttpService: AppHttpService
      ) {}
    
     
      loadHelpMenu$: Observable<Action> = createEffect(() =>
        this.actions$.pipe(
          ofType(AppActions.loadHelpMenu),
          concatMap(() =>
            this.appHttpService.getHelpMenuItems().pipe(
              map((result: HelpMenu) =>
                AppActions.helpMenuLoaded({
                  helpmenu: result,
                })
              ),
              catchError((error) =>
                of(
                  AppActions.helpMenuFailed({
                    error,
                  })
                )
              )
            )
          )
        )
      );
    
    
    
      loadUserProfile$ = createEffect(
        () => this.actions$.pipe(
            ofType(AppActions.loadUserProfile),
            concatMap(action => this.appHttpService.getProfileDetails(action.userId).pipe(
              map((result:UserProfile) => {
                let userName = new UserName();
                userName.firstName = result.firstName;
                userName.lastName = result.lastName;
                return AppActions.setUserName({ userName });
              }),
              catchError((error) => 
                of(
                  AppActions.loadUserProfileFail(error)
                )
              )
            )
          )
        )
      );
    }
```

The test spec I wrote
**app.effects.spec.ts**

```js
    import { Observable } from "rxjs";
    import { AppEffects } from './app.effects';
    import { MockStore, provideMockStore } from '@ngrx/store/testing';
    import { AppState } from './reducers';
    import { AppHttpService } from './core/services/app.http.service';
    import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
    import { provideMockActions } from '@ngrx/effects/testing';
    class MockService{
    
    }
    describe('AppEffects', () => {
        let actions$: Observable<any>;
        let effects: AppEffects;
        let store: MockStore<AppState>;
        let httpService: AppHttpService;
      beforeEach(() => {
          TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            providers: [
              AppEffects,
              provideMockStore(),
              provideMockActions(() => actions$),
              { provide: AppHttpService, useClass: MockService },
            ],
          });
          effects = TestBed.get(AppEffects);
          store = TestBed.get(MockStore);
          httpService = TestBed.get(AppHttpService);
        });
        it('should be created', () => {
            expect(effects).toBeTruthy();
          });
      });
```

The error message I get every time I run the test is this

```
Error: Can't resolve all parameters for AppEffects: (?, ?).
error properties: Object({ ngSyntaxError: true })
```

There were only two classes that I am injecting to AppEffect class  Actions and an HTTP service. I am providing a mock class for HTTP service too I still get the error

Comment: Could you create a StackBlitz demo ?

Answer (score 0):

This problem usually occurs when a service with dependencies to be injected into them is not injectable. In your case it should be `@Injectable()` I think, not `Injectable()`